# Why does the terminal say "invalid operands to binary expression"? C

Tags: c, cs50

This is the error that the terminal gives out:

```
greedy.c:26:21: error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('float' and 'float')
        float x = x % q;
                  ~ ^ ~
1 error generated.
```

From the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) 
{
    float x;
    float y = 0;
    float q = 25.0;
    float d = 10.0;
    float n = 5.0;
    float p = 1.0;

    printf("How much I owe you? Enter here: ");

    x = GetFloat();

    while (x <= 0)
    {
        printf("Please enter the sum with a decimal point (e.g. .50; 1.37): ");
        x = GetFloat();
    } 

    if (x > 25.0) 
    {
        float x = x % q;
        y++;
    }

    printf("The modulo of %f and the coins used: %f\n", x, y);

}
```

I think that you are acquainted with the CS50 "greedy" task. I need to get the remainder of `x`. Maybe I have missed something in the tutorial, but I think they didn't specify how to use the modulo `%` operator.

Comment: I don't think the `%` modulus operator works on `float`s. You may want to look into `fmod()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modulo operator only work with integer types. You want to use the [`fmodf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod) function.